# redirect to other page once click close the current page in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am new to JavaScript Programming. What I want to do is the following: 
I am opening popup window for the user to print something. once he finishes, he will close the page. I want the portal to open another page once he closes this page. I tried the following:

```
<body onbeforeunload="window.open('BondData.aspx');">
```

but it does not work. Can you please guide me to an idea where I can get this working?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Add this code on page on which you going to close

```
<script >
window.onbeforeunload =      

  function ()
    {

    window.open('NewPage.aspx');
    };
</script >
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works if I use it with submit button. But what I want to use it if the page is closed by the user from the x not by clicking one button.

Comment: It is does not work. It tries to open new page but it directly close the current page and the new one.

Comment: @HussainAhmed then what is your requirement

Comment: This is exactly my requirement but it does not work. Once it open the new window, it directly close both the new one and the old one. I want it to only close the old one and keep the current one. Thanks in advance.